# How to know if my app is currently used in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I want to perform a task continuously in my iOS application. If my application is in the foreground, it's working as expected. But the moment it enters into the background or is in sleep mode, it stops working.

How can I implement this in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Finite-Length tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) to execute some task when your app is going in to the background. This will allow your app the to finish a task with a given time (10min. max).

The other option is to look if your app falls in any of the [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23). But be aware that is you misses the background mode to keep you app a live in the background apple will reject your app.

If the task is an update task, like to retrieve new information, you should move this task to a server and use Push Notifications to alert the user of update. You can even combine it with a background fetch which will allow you app the retrieve the information in the background.